# Azure AD Group user sees Forbidden error while accessing Manage ACL for Azure DataLake Container

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

An Azure Storage Account is created with DataLake Storage via Terraform. And Below permissions exist for the user. But User keep getting error while performing `Storage Browser > Manage ACL > Access Permissions Tab > Forbidden`

Error:
[image]

RBAC Permissions of User on SA:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error **"Forbidden"** usually occurs if your user doesn't have sufficient permissions or the access is blocked by a firewall.

As your user already has **required** roles, you can check the configuration settings of your storage account in **`Networking`** tab whether public access is enabled or not.

I have one Datalake storage account where public access is **disabled** like below:

[image]

When I tried to perform same action as you with user having **proper** roles, I got **same error** saying **`Forbidden`** like below:

*Go to Azure Portal -> Storage Account -> Storage Browser -> Container -> Manage ACL -> Access Permissions Tab*

[image]

To resolve the error, you can either **enable** public access or add user's IP under Firewall to allow access, if you prefer **selected** virtual networks and IP addresses.

In my case, I enabled **public access** in my Datalake storage account like below:

[image]

When I tried to perform the same action again after enabling public access, user can **manage ACL** successfully like below:

*Go to Azure Portal -> Storage Account -> Storage Browser -> Container -> Manage ACL -> Access Permissions Tab*

[image]

In your case, check configuration settings in `Networking` tab of your storage account and **modify** the settings accordingly to resolve the error.

Comment: Hi, the publick network access is set to `Enabled from selected virtual networks and IP addresses`. There is requirement to keep it non-public.

Comment: Then, make sure to add user's IP under the Firewall to allow access like [this](https://i.imgur.com/HW5joT1.png).

Answer (score 1):

It seems the issue was missing private endpoint for the DFS type sub-resource:

From the [Azure Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-private-endpoints#creating-a-private-endpoint):

> If you create a private endpoint for the Data Lake Storage Gen2 storage resource, then you should also create one for the Blob Storage resource. That's because operations that target the Data Lake Storage Gen2 endpoint might be redirected to the Blob endpoint. Similarly, if you add a private endpoint for Blob Storage only, and not for Data Lake Storage Gen2, some operations (such as Manage ACL, Create Directory, Delete Directory, etc.) will fail since the Gen2 APIs require a DFS private endpoint. By creating a private endpoint for both resources, you ensure that all operations can complete successfully.

So creating a private endpoint for DFS fixed the ACL issue.